exterior home paint
My exterior paint on the aluminum siding is fading and chalky. It's probably 50 years old. We're starting to see another color come through but have no details from the prior owner. My question is how important is the color on the siding? Is it purely aesthetic or is there an importance to the paint on the siding? I'd prefer to push the project of painting it down the line but don't understand if fading paint could create some type of problem I don't realize. Thanks!

Paint is a protectant.  It should be done more sooner than  later.   Even though you have aluminium, you need to protect the surface to prevent oxidation.
